# Jackson YAML: mapping a regex Pattern with flags

Tags: java, regex, jackson, yaml

In Jackson, [I can map](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-yaml#simple-usage) a string in YAML:

```
regexField: "(\\d{2}):(\\d{2})"
```

to a `Pattern` field on a class:

```
final class MappedFromYaml {
    private Pattern regexField;
    // ... accessors
}
```

Jackson's `ObjectMapper` will create a `Pattern` with default flags. Is it possible to make it create it with specific flags set, such as `Pattern.MULTILINE`? Ideally I would like to be able to specify those flags in YAML, but failing that a solution that specifies the flags for a specific field in Java code would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways. The first is embedding flags directly [into the regex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE):

```
regexField: "(\\d{2}):(\\d{2})(?m)"
```

Otherwise don't map directly to `Pattern`, but introduce a custom type like a `PatternBuilder`

```
public class PatternBuilder {
  public String regex;
  public boolean multiline;
  public Pattern pattern() {
    int flags = 0;
    if (multiline) flags |= Pattern.MULTILINE;
    return Pattern.compile(regex, flags);
  }
}
```

that can be built from the YAML

```
pattern:
  regex: "(\\d{2}):(\\d{2})"
  multiline: true
```

Comment: Thanks, the flag in the regex is exactly what I was looking for!